# Reassigning exported operators in R

Tags: r, foreach

I encountered a problem in my workflow with `R` that prevents me from using certain kinds of parallelization.

In this particular case, `myCustomPackage` imports and uses `problematic_function` which is exported from `anotherPackage`. `problematic_function` uses `%dopar%` operator from `foreach` for certain calculations and hence imports it from `foreach`. Due to certain reasons usage of `%dopar%` results in errors and I would like to find a workaround that I could apply on the fly.

Since parallelization is not really essential in this case, as a short-term solution I would like to fully override `%dopar%` by replacing it with `%do%` everywhere, which actually works fine in my case.

I tried several variations of `assignInNamespace('%dopar%', '%do%', 'foreach')` but with little success.
Maybe someone has a better idea on this? I'd really like to avoid messing with the source code of `anotherPackage` for the time being.

**EDIT**. To illustrate with a more concrete example, here's an equivalent issue. How to make this code run with `%do%` despite `allowParallel = TRUE`.

```
library(caret)
library(party)

library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
library(parallel)

data(BloodBrain)
cl <- makeCluster(1)
registerDoParallel(cl)
treebag <- bag(bbbDescr, logBBB, B = 10,
               bagControl = bagControl(fit = ctreeBag$fit,
                                       predict = ctreeBag$pred,
                                       aggregate = ctreeBag$aggregate,
                                       allowParallel = TRUE))
```

```

Comment: It would be much easier to help you if you provided some sort of minimal [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with specific functions that can be used for testing.

Comment: I'm not trying to solve a bug with `foreach` (there's likely no bug here), I just encountered an issue during deployment and trying to find a quick workaround. There's not much too reproduce here. I'll edit the question to give a more concrete idea.

Comment: registerDoSeq() won't work?

Comment: In the particular example it might but `anotherPackage` does its own `registerDoParallel`, so probably no.